# How to move down many UITextFields if a new UITextField is added

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield

I have a ViewController, many UITextFields (the one under the other) and a button on the right at first UITextField.

When the button is pressed, I want another UITextField displayed under this (every time I push the button a textfield will be created under the other) **and move** the others some pixels down.

How can I do that? I thought I must make a new UIView with InterfaceBuilder with the textfields in it that will move down some pixels but I can't do that.

[image: MyView:]

Answer (score 1):

What about using a UITableViewController? Basically you could set as a first section the first UITextField (inside a UITableViewCell) and the rest of the fields in a second section. Then, every time the button is pressed you insert a new cell in the first section.

It would be easy to manage the insertion and deletion of fields, without having to handle manually the movement of the view (they're handled automatically by the UITableView), all you have to do is update the datasource (number of cells) and reload/insert the cells (reloadData or insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

Comment: Can i add textfields to the cells with interface builder or i have to create them programmatically?

Comment: If you're using a UITableViewController with Storyboard you can create UITableViewCell's prototypes with a UITextField inside (directly from Interface Builder).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a very easy solution if you like is by using a variable in the place of **y co-ordinate** in a CGRectMake co-ordinates.

A little more detail:

You have to create all the UITextField's programmatically and whenever you alloc initwithFrame any UITextField use a variable like:

```
int y = 10; // By default value and make it a property and define in viewDidLoad or wherever

UITextField *txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20 +y, 100, 50)];
        // set TextFields other values
[self addSubview:txtField1];

UITextField *txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80+y, 100, 50)];
        // set TextFields other values
[self addSubview:txtField1];
```

Now, whenever you click on add UITextField button, increase the value of y by the space extra you want, like:

```
-(void)onTapAddTextFieldButton{
    y= y + 40;
}
```